# Subscribe to a post on Blogspot?

Tags: blogger, comments

If I comment on a blog post on `whateverblog.blogspot.com`, and I want to get an email notification when there are further replies / comments on that post, how would I go about that?

As an example 
http://atheistexperience.blogspot.com/2011/07/god-based-abortion-policy-fail-open.html

Comment: It depends on the blog, I think, as they could be using the Blogger-supplied commenting system, or a third party commenting system.

Comment: well if it's the native one or as you say "blogger supplied".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This largely depends on if the Blogspot user allows people to subscribe to the comments. If they do, you will see the option when you click through to view the comments for the post.

At the bottom of the page (or on the side depending on their layout) there usually is a link in the form of:

> Subscribe to: **Post Comments (Atom)**

That will lead to a link of the RSS for the comments on that post. It's in the following format:

```
http://example.blogspot.com/feeds/{generated-post-ID}/comments/default
```

Use the above as the RSS feed URL for your reader. Or if you want to have it sent to you through email, find a feed-to-email service that suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the comments page and find out the RSS feed URL (look out for the [image: RSS icon] icon on your browser, just click on it and use the URL you get (Firefox shows the icon by default but not from version 4  on (you need to get it from the advanced menu), IE shows it from version 7 on (it has a star if the website has a feed) and on Chrome you need [an extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd))).

Use a service that mails you updates of the feed URL you got:

- [feedmyinbox](http://www.feedmyinbox.com/) (free only for daily updates)
- [feedmailer](http://www.feedmailer.net/)
- [Blog Alert](http://www.shootthebreeze.net/blogalert/index.php) (daily only)
- [RSS to Email Gateway](http://reblinks.therssweblog.com/) (doesn't provide information on how often you receive updates)

Comment: i've added an example in the question, a URL of a post which i'd want updates on, I don't see an RSS option

Comment: I see the feed http://atheistexperience.blogspot.com/feeds/5149730051260020966/comments/default (which is in the form that @eight described) (which is actually atom, sorry for simplification)

Comment: was still a very good answer.. I used the feedmyinbox link you mentioned. The generic paragraph at the top of your answer was good but didn't quite cover my case, eight's one also generic i think, happened to cover it. no need to apologise!